# How to get the `code` property of an error in a `try/catch` using TypeScript 4.4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get to the `code` property of an error caught by `try/catch` like so:

```js
  try {
    const { foo } = await import('./foo');
    // [...]
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      if (error.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
         // [...]
      }
    }
  }
```

but this gives me the following compilation error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/server.ts:44:17 - error TS2339: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.
```

I installed `@types/node@16.x.x` and my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

but I noticed that Visual Studio Code gets the definition for the Error class from:

```
C:\Users\kg\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es5.d.ts
```

How do I make TypeScript see that there's a `code` property in `Error` without having to define my own type or interface?

Comment: If you review the properties of [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/error) is `code` a property that exists on type `Error`? Do you have a custom error that you include a custom property `code`? If it is a custom error, as in has custom properties like `code`, you should create the appropriate class/type to reflect that.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky according to the Node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/errors.html), there is indeed a `code` property, but it seems as though it's missing in the interface definition in the mentioned file.

Comment: Didn't realize this was in node, thought this could perhaps be in the browser. However it does look like you are compiling this to es5? If you change the compile target,  to something newer like es6 or above, does that change the result?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky my `tsconfig.json` extends [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/node16) one, which targets "es2021".

Comment: Thank you, @JeffBowman! I've been trying to solve this for a couple hours now and for some reason I didn't find that SO question. It's exactly the same problem that I have. Unfortunately, the solution is ugly as hell. Bummer.